# iOS JSon parsing, array in array

Tags: ios, json

I have a simple json format with an array within an array, but I can't figure out how to get the inner array.  How do I grab the "Commute" tag as an `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`?

Here is my json:

```
{
    "Language": "EN",
    "Place": [
        {
            "City": "Stockholm",
            "Name": "Slussen",
            "Commute": [
                "Subway",
                "Bus"
            ]
        },
        {
            "City": "Gothenburg",
            "Name": "Central station",
            "Commute": [
                "Train",
                "Bus"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
NSString *textPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Places" ofType:@"json"];

NSError *error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];  //error checking omitted

NSData *jsonData = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSArray* AllPlaces = [json objectForKey:@"Place"];

for(int n = 0; n < [AllPlaces count]; n++)
{
    PlaceItem* item     = [[PlaceItem alloc]init];
    NSDictionary* place = [AllPlaces objectAtIndex:n];
    item.City           = [place objectForKey:@"City"];
    item.Name           = [place objectForKey:@"Name"];

    NSDictionary* commutes = [json objectForKey:@"Commute"];

    [self.placeArray addObject:(item)];
}
```

Comment: Commute is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: Please find another one-line method to get all you want [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21112069/2066428)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be:

```
NSArray* commutes = [place objectForKey:@"Commute"];
```

Thwt would give back an array holding `"Subway"` and `"Bus"`.

Comment: Most likely a typo but that json dictionary does not contain an element keyed by "Commute".

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the access to `json`, it should be `place` instead:

```
NSArray* commutes = [place objectForKey:@"Commute"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *commutes = [place objectForKey:@"Commute"];
```

This will give you an `NSArray` with "Subway" and "Bus".

Answer (score 0):

You can considerably shrink you code using KVC Collection Operators:

```
NSArray *commutes = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Place.@distinctUnionOfArrays.Commute"];
```

If you want all repeated commutes use @unionOfArrays modifier.